# Transferring set of points to Bezier curve

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing, bezier

In my WPF application I'm working on a drawing mechanism to make annotations on top of images. For now I have functionality to draw paths where my drawn path will consist of the collected points from the drawing. More closely I'm adding StylusPoints to an InkPresenter as I collect them through the MouseMoved event. The InkPresenter is set as child to a Canvas, which then is what will hold the drawings. I could also draw a LineSegment in a Path if that's any different?

My problem with this drawing is that it won't be smooth. Therefore I'd like the resulting curve to be represented as a Bezier curve. This is a technique used e.g. in Adobe Illustrator. Now; is there a way to handle this? To first build a collection of points that represents the bumpy curve drawn, and then transform this to a Bezier curve which resembles the drawn curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fit a curve to a set of points, think spline (of which Bezier is a subset).

[Here is a PDF about how to fit a Bezier to four points](http://www.tinaja.com/glib/bez4pts.pdf), easily extended to n.  This came from Don Lancaster's guru's lair, which has a great set of [tutorials on Beziers](http://www.tinaja.com/cubic01.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Charles Petzold has a class CanonicalSpline in the sample code for his Line Chart With Data Templates article in MSDN Magazine.

[Sample Code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201001Charts)

The key method of the class creates a PathGeometry from a set of points.